# Javascript: replace() function not working in Mac safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have the below set of code to replace specific tags from string.It's not working in Mac safari but working properly in windows chrome and firefox.

Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'n.innerHTML.replace')

```
html_data = html_data.replace(/para/g, "p");
html_data = html_data.replace(/useful/g, "span");
html_data = html_data.replace(/extra_info/g, "span");
```

Comment: Have you declare html_data correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have declared html_data as var html_data = '';

Comment: it appears that your problem is with `.innerHTML` rather than with `.replace`

Comment: sorry take a look : http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Internet_Email/Web_Browsers/Q_24716051.html

Answer (score 1):

Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'n.innerHTML.replace')

this means that either n is undefined, or n.innerHTML is undefined. It is not about replace function.
Since you did not submit the full code, can you check which one is undefined?

Comment: `n` is defined, otherwise attempting `.innerHTML` on `undefined` would throw the error

Answer (score 0):

Your error message indicates that you are trying to call the `.replace` method of an undefined object.

Therefore your problem is that either `n` or `n.innerHTML` is undefined (for reasons that cannot be discerned given the limited information we have) and nothing to do with `.replace` at all.

Comment: I have used Jquery plugin version 1.10.2.

Comment: @pratiknagariya that's completely irrelevant.

Comment: in which case you need to supply way more information in your question.  For a start, the code you quoted isn't part of the jQuery source code, so how can you possibly be getting that error "in the jQuery plugin" ?!